# News Ticker not working on wordpress pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming, wordpress, news-ticker

Jquery ticker working on my site [home page](http://www.news.shreshthbharat.in/) perfectly , but not working on pages . I dont know why.

On pages this ticker not is showing posts, it shows only the page list.

Here is code of TICKER on header

```
 <div class="fl" id="hotnews">
 <ul id="shreshth_news" class="shr_news">
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <li><span class="heading"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a>  </span><span class="info"></span></li>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 </ul></div>
```

This ticker working smoothly on single.php index.php etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this instead of above code

```
<div class="fl" id="hotnews">
<ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden">
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query('showposts=5&orderby=post_date&order=desc');
            while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?> 
<li><span class="heading"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>    </span><span class="info"></span></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul></div>
```